# How to use "use-percentages" on Compass?

Tags: sass, sprite, background-position, compass

I'm trying to use `use_percentages` to generate an image sprite with background position by percentage. But after compiling the SCSS file, the `background-position` declaration is still in pixels.

My SASS code:

```
@import "compass/utilities/sprites";

$sprite-layout:smart;
$sprite-sprite-dimensions: true;
$use-percentages: true;

@import "images/sprite/*.png";
@include all-sprite-sprites;
```

How can I get the sprite images to be positioned by percentages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to include the name of your sprite map in the variable when specifying the `use-percentages` parameter, as you have already done for `layout`. So just change `$use-percentages: true;` to `$sprite-use-percentages: true;`.