# How to get responsive sprite images?

Tags: css, responsive-design, sass, sprite, compass

I am able to generate my sprites images using SASS and Compass. Until here all work fine. The problem I am facing is I have no idea how to achieve the sprites be responsive.

I found [this sit](http://responsive-css.spritegen.com/)e that generates responsive sprites such I pretend but I don't know how to do it with using SASS and Compass. Is there some mixin that lets me do something like this?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26467557/how-to-use-use-percentages-on-compass

Comment: Not, that post doesn't explain how to make responsive the sprite images. I've followed the given examples but I just get different sprites image sizes in order to use in media queries according to what I understood
I just want my sprite images be responsive, I mean they adapt to its container width.
Any idea?

Comment: The only thing special the generator you link to does over the default behavior of Compass is that it uses percentages for the background-size.  There's also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19341929/compass-sprite-image-and-scale